# QtCreator Automatically Runs CMake

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

It is kind of annoying but qtCreator runs CMake over and over while I would like to run CMake only when I need it.

Do you know where can I find this option and modify it to have the desired behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is crazy how this happens regularly to me. I try to find the solution to a problem. I don't succeed. I write the question here and then I found the solutuion in the following 10 minutes.

Anyway, I understood how to solve my problem.

I am in qtCreator 4.1.0.

Go in Tools-->Options-->Build and Run-->CMake
Click on the *System CMake at ...* line

On the bottom of this GUI it will appear something like *Name* *Path* and **Autorun CMake**.

Just deselect this last thickbox and CMake will not run anymore by itself.

I hope it will help someone in my same situation.